# Can I find e-mails, sent over MS-Exchange, using MS-Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, wireshark

I'm working with MS-Outlook and I would like to see the mails I'm sending in a wireshark capture. I tried filtering on "SMTP" but there's nothing.

How can I see my sent and received mails in a Wireshark capture?

I'm working with MS-Outlook over a "Microsoft Exchange" account.

P.s. I already filtered on "smtp", "pop" and "imap" but there's nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible, as the traffic is encoded.

In order to see this, I've done a `netstat -aon | findstr  24612` where 24612 is the current process ID of `Outlook.exe`. This revealed the following:

```
TCP    10.1.13.317:54626      10.1.6.23:443          ESTABLISHED     24612
TCP    10.1.13.317:54700      10.1.6.23:443          ESTABLISHED     24612
TCP    10.1.13.317:55190      10.1.6.23:443          ESTABLISHED     24612
UDP    127.0.0.1:52573        *:*                                    24612
```

The port 443 means that "HTTPS" is used, hence the communication is encrypted and can't be read using a sniffer, like Wireshark.

Comment: Yes, it's not feasible. Per my research, mails sent over Exchange is protected by TLS encryption, so you can also see traffic rather than the message details using tools like wireshark

Answer (score 1):

See the article
[Capturing network traffic between outlook client and exchange server (RPC over TCP)](http://csharptechies.blogspot.com/2011/12/capturing-network-traffic-between.html).

This is a summary :

- Open wireshark and click on the interface to start capturing network traffic
- Start outlook perform routine tasks for some time
- Stop capturing
- Save your capture
- Specify your filter as `ip.src == 1.2.3.4 and ip.dst == 1.2.3.5`
  Use the exchange server IP address as destination.
- Select *Statistics > Summary* to see some useful traffic information.

More information and screenshots can be found in the article.